# How to show € symbol in a kendo grid cell

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i need help about formatting a kendo grid cell.
I need to show the € symbol, in a cell of my kendo grid, but it shows me always the $ symbol.
I included the js file

```
    <script src="../js/cultures/kendo.culture.it-IT.min.js"></script>
```

then this is the model.filed definition:

```
price: { type: "number"}
```

and here is the column.field definition

```
        {
            field: "price", title: "Price", width: 100, culture: "it-IT", format: "{0:c}"
        }
```

.... and another question... can I represent that type of data in a field of "string"  type???

any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling `kendo.culture("it-IT");` on your page before the grid is created ?

Yes, you can specify a template for the price field, and turn it into a string, or you can just specify the type in model.

```
price: { type: 'string' }
```

And kendo will convert it.

Answer (score 0):

For Example:In kendo Grid Field like money or salary .Which showed with currency format.
By using below code.
`kendo.culture("en-US"); 
kendo.toString(1.00, "c0");`
Which gives $1.00
Do you show € symbol: kendo.culture("de-DE"); use this format